# How does a PHP server recognize API request types?

Tags: parsing, post, amazon-ec2, get, postman

My EC2 server is successfully parsing the endpoint paths and parameters from Postman GET queries (and returning the JSON with appropriate success code). When I send a POST query, using POSTMAN, it contains a body, but the request headers are the same.

Is a standard API POST request recognized as such simply because it has a body? What if the body is being used for GET parameters? Then how are PUT or DELETE requests recognized? Please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: It turns out that, for PHP, the request type is in $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD’].

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the request contains the request type, the target and the http version:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
```

The headers come after that, then a blank line, and then the body, if any.

Perhaps whatever you are using to show you the request isn't showing you the request line itself, or perhaps it's showing you that in a different place.